# Abstract Algebra Subgroup Proof Help

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that if N is a normal subgroup of G and |N| = 2, then N is a subgroup of Z(G).

proof: Let N be a normal subgroup of G. Then N is a subgroup of G and g is in G. So gN = Ng for all g in G. Suppose |N| = 2.

Then I am stuck on where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Well, $N = \{e, n\}$. So $gN = \{g, gn\}$ and $Ng = \{g, ng\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ of order two.  Thus, $N = \{e,n\} \subseteq G$.  Moreover, for all $g \in G$ we have that $\{g,gn\} = gN = Ng = \{g,ng\}$.  Hence $gn = ng$ for all $g \in G$, and so $n \in Z(G)$.